# QT3D Multiview - Single View in Widget

Tags: qt, qt3d

I have a question regarding the "Qt 3D: Multi Viewport QML Example" [Link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-multiviewport-example.html)

Is there a possibility to add a single view (one of the four in the example) into a separate widget. I tried to change the example but I only could add all four views to one widget.

The following code creates a camera which should be displayed in a separate Widget. see Picture

[image]

I am not sure if it is possible and how i can solve it.

```
SimpleCamera {
    id: camera4
    lens: cameraLens3
    position: Qt.vector3d(100.0, 0.0, -6.0)
    viewCenter: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, -6.0)
}
```

Comment: Try adding the relevant detail from your link into your question and show more specifically what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I only know how to achieve this using C++: In this case, you create your Qt3DWindow and place it inside a widget using QWidget::createWindowContainer. This returns a widget which you can then use in your UI. You can do this for multiple different 3D windows, although performance suffers at some point. I'm not sure if you can reuse the framegraph, though as Qt's documentation often states that objects should not be shared, but you could try and see what happens.

Comment: I already created a windowContainer but i do not know how to display a single view (e.g. one of the four views). Currently all four views are displayed inside the widget. If i could solve this i want to extend it that all four views are displayes in four separate widgets.

Answer (score 1):

In the example, the four views are created using the classes [Viewport](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qt3d-render-viewport.html) and [CameraSelector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-render-cameraselector.html).

**The Viewport class**

The class `Viewport` defines the portion of the screen that the branch of the framegraph (that the `Viewport` node is part of) is rendered to. The portion is defined as `(x, y, width, height)`. The coordinates of the whole screen are `(0, 0, 1, 1)`.

If you have a look at the `QuadViewportFrameGraph` class that is part of the example, you'll see four viewports defined - one for each camera. The top left camera renders to the rectangle `(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5)` of the screen. The top right camera on the other hand renders to `(0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5)`, i.e. it uses half of the screen size as its `x` offset.

**The CameraSelector class**

This class defines which camera the branch of the framegraph uses to render content. If you look into the example you'll see a `CameraSelector { id: someCamera }` within each `Viewport` instance. This way, each `Viewport` gets its own camera.

**Conclusion**

If you only want one view, remove the four `Viewports` within the main `Viewport` and add one camera selector as the child of it. So your `QuadViewportFrameGraph` should look like this (without import statements):

```
RenderSettings {
    id: quadViewportFrameGraph

    property alias camera: cameraSelector.camera;
    property alias window: surfaceSelector.surface

    activeFrameGraph: RenderSurfaceSelector {
        id: surfaceSelector

        Viewport {
            id: mainViewport
            normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0, 0, 1, 1)

            ClearBuffers {
                buffers: ClearBuffers.ColorDepthBuffer
                clearColor: Qt.rgba(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0)

                CameraSelector { id: cameraSelector }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you also have to adjust the code where you instantiate the `QuadViewportFrameGraph` and only set the one camera. If you now want all four views displayed in separate widgets you need to create four 3D windows and window containers and such a framegraph for each (with different cameras of course).

But be warned that the performance might be crappy if you create for distinct 3D windows. As far as I know, there are no other solutions to obtain 3D widgets.

Comment: Nice answer. Any ideas on [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64903558/176769)?