# Qt3D: How to scale a Scene2D to be the same size as the window (pixel-wise)?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt3d

I created a C++ application with a 800x600 window that successfully draws a few objects in QML using Qt Quick 2 elements as well as Qt 3D objects:

[image]

The QML code draws a couple of green/yellow rectangles using Qt Quick 2 `Rectangle` elements inside a `Scene2D`. Then the 2D scene is blitted to one of the surfaces of a 3D cube for rendering and be displayed within the 3D world. Finally, a blue `SphereMesh` from Qt 3D is rendered at the center as the screenshot above demonstrates.

I've been trying to resize the 3D cube (where the 2D UI is being rendered to) so that it has the same size as the window but I can't find a way to do it programatically:

[image]

So the question is **how to resize or scale the 3D cube so that it is automatically adjusted to have the same size as the window?**

I'm looking for a solution that allows the cube to have the same amount of pixels as the window. For instance, on an 800x600 window I would like to see an 800x600 green rectangle.

Here is what I tried: I can adjust the value of `camZ` by hand, which is the distance of the `Camera` with the center of the 3D world, and kinda eyeball it, but that's not a precise solution: if the window is changed later to a different dimension, I would need to do a lot of testing again to figure out what the new value for `camZ` must be.

Any ideas?

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include <Qt3DQuickExtras/qt3dquickwindow.h>
#include <Qt3DQuick/QQmlAspectEngine>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Qt3DExtras::Quick::Qt3DQuickWindow view;
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    auto rootContext = view.engine()->qmlEngine()->rootContext();
    rootContext->setContextProperty("_window", &view);
    view.resize(800, 600);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**:

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.12
import Qt3D.Render 2.12
import Qt3D.Extras 2.12
import Qt3D.Input 2.12

import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Scene2D 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Entity
{
    id: sceneRoot
    property int w: _window.width
    property int h: _window.height
    property real camZ: 1000

    /* setup camera */

    Camera {
        id: mainCamera
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        fieldOfView: 45
        aspectRatio: _window.width / _window.height
        nearPlane:   0.01
        farPlane: 1000000.0
        position:    Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, sceneRoot.camZ )
        viewCenter:  Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
        upVector:    Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
    }

    components: [
        RenderSettings {
            activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
                camera: mainCamera
                clearColor: "white"
            }
            pickingSettings.pickMethod: PickingSettings.TrianglePicking
        },

        InputSettings {}
    ]

    /* setup a 3D cube to be used as the 2D drawing surface for all Qt Quick 2 stuff */

    Entity {
        id: drawingSurface

        CuboidMesh {
            id: planeMesh
        }

        Transform {
            id: planeTransform
            translation: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0)
            scale3D: Qt.vector3d(sceneRoot.w, sceneRoot.h, 1)
        }

        TextureMaterial {
            id: planeMaterial
            texture: offscreenTexture  // created by qmlTexture below
        }

        // picked up by Scene2D’s "entities" property and used as a source for events
        ObjectPicker {
            id: planePicker
            hoverEnabled: false
            dragEnabled: false
        }

        components: [ planeMesh, planeMaterial, planeTransform, planePicker ]
    }

    /* setup Scene2D offscreen texture to be used as canvas by Qt Quick 2 */

    Scene2D {
        id: qmlTexture
        output: RenderTargetOutput {
            attachmentPoint: RenderTargetOutput.Color0
            texture: Texture2D {
                id: offscreenTexture
                width: sceneRoot.w
                height: sceneRoot.h
                format: Texture.RGBA8_UNorm
                generateMipMaps: true
                magnificationFilter: Texture.Linear
                minificationFilter: Texture.LinearMipMapLinear
                wrapMode {
                    x: WrapMode.ClampToEdge
                    y: WrapMode.ClampToEdge
                }
            }
        }

        mouseEnabled: false
        entities: [ drawingSurface ]

        /* Qt Quick 2 rendering */

        Rectangle {
            width: offscreenTexture.width
            height: offscreenTexture.height
            x: 0
            y: 0
            border.color: "red"
            color: "green"

            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log("Outter rectangle size: " + width + "x" + height + " at " + x + "," + y);
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: innerRect
                height: parent.height*0.6
                width: height
                x: (parent.width/2) - (width/2)
                y: (parent.height/2) - (height/2)
                border.color: "red"
                color: "yellow"
                transform: Rotation { origin.x: innerRect.width/2; origin.y: innerRect.height/2; angle: 45}

                Component.onCompleted: {
                    console.log("Inner rectangle size: " + width + "x" + height + " at " + x + "," + y);
                }
            }
        }

    } // Scene2D

    /* add light source at the same place as the camera */

    Entity {
        PointLight {
            id: light
            color: "white"
            intensity: 1
            constantAttenuation: 1.0
            linearAttenuation: 0.0
        }

        Transform {
            id: lightTransform
            translation: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, sceneRoot.camZ)
        }

        components: [ light, lightTransform ]
    }

    /* display 3D object */

    Entity {
        SphereMesh {
            id: mesh
            radius: 130
        }

        PhongMaterial {
            id: material
            ambient: "blue"
        }

        Transform {
           id: transform
           translation: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0)
       }

       components: [ mesh, material, transform ]
   }

} // sceneRoot
```

Add these modules to your .pro file:

```
QT += qml quick 3dquick 3dquickextras
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, when you want to a texture to cover the whole screen you use [orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection). In contrast to perspective projection objects will always appear the same size on the screen no matter their distance from the camera. This type of projection is often used to visualize 3D plans of buildings etc. or to render UI elements in 3D.

The idea is now that you have to framegraph branches:

1. Draws the background image
2. Draws all the objects

```
                     RenderSurfaceSelector
                                |
                             Viewport
                                |
          -------------------------------------------
          |             |             |             |
     ClearBuffers  LayerFilter   ClearBuffers  LayerFilter
          |             |             |             |
        NoDraw    CameraSelector    NoDraw    CameraSelector
```

The first (from left to right) clear buffers clears all buffers. The first layer filter filters for the background layer (which you have to attach to the background entity). The second clear buffers clears only depth (so that the objects get definitely drawn). The second layer filter filters for the main layer (which you have to attach to all objects you want to get drawn).

You then create the background camera and set its projection type to orthographic projection:

```
Camera {
        id: backgroundCamera
        projectionType: CameraLens.OrthographicProjection
        fieldOfView: 45
        aspectRatio: sceneRoot.w / sceneRoot.h
        left: - sceneRoot.w / 2
        right: sceneRoot.w / 2
        bottom: - sceneRoot.h / 2
        top: sceneRoot.h / 2
        nearPlane:   0.1
        farPlane:    1000.0
        position:    Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 )
        viewCenter:  Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
        upVector:    Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
}
```

You could also choose `-1` and `1` for left - right and bottom - top instead of `sceneRoot.w` and `sceneRoot.h`. In thise case you would have to adjust the textured plane's size to `(2, 2)`. I wanted to draw the clicks a user made on a texture once that's why I went with the screen sizes.

*A side note:* Don't use values that are very high or very low for the `nearPlane` and `farPlane`. It says in the Qt3D documentation (somewhere, can't find it right now) that when the far plane is set to greater 100.000 inaccuracies will occur. Also, if you set it too small the same will happen. You can read on it on the internet, it's a general problem in 3D computer grahpics.

Well, here's the full code:

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.12
import Qt3D.Render 2.12
import Qt3D.Extras 2.12
import Qt3D.Input 2.12

import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Scene2D 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Entity
{
    id: sceneRoot
    property int w: _window.width
    property int h: _window.height
    property real camZ: 1000

    components: [
        RenderSettings {
            activeFrameGraph:  RenderSurfaceSelector {
                id: surfaceSelector

                Viewport {
                    id: mainViewport
                    normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0, 0, 1, 1)

                    ClearBuffers {
                        buffers: ClearBuffers.ColorDepthBuffer
                        clearColor: Qt.rgba(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0)

                        NoDraw {
                            // Prevent drawing here, we only want to clear the buffers
                        }
                    }

                    LayerFilter {
                        id: backgroundLayerFilter

                        layers: [backgroundLayer]

                        CameraSelector {
                            id: backgroundCameraSelector
                            camera: backgroundCamera
                        }
                    }

                    ClearBuffers {
                        buffers: ClearBuffers.DepthBuffer

                        NoDraw {
                            // Prevent drawing here, we only want to clear the buffers
                        }
                    }

                    LayerFilter {
                        id: mainLayerFilter

                        layers: [mainLayer]

                        CameraSelector {
                            id: mainCameraSelector
                            camera: mainCamera
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            pickingSettings.pickMethod: PickingSettings.TrianglePicking
        },

        InputSettings {}
    ]

    Camera {
        id: mainCamera
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        fieldOfView: 45
        aspectRatio: _window.width / _window.height
        nearPlane:   0.1
        farPlane:    1000.0
        position:    Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, camZ )
        viewCenter:  Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
        upVector:    Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
    }

    /* setup camera */

    Camera {
        id: backgroundCamera
        projectionType: CameraLens.OrthographicProjection
        fieldOfView: 45
        aspectRatio: sceneRoot.w / sceneRoot.h
        left: - sceneRoot.w / 2
        right: sceneRoot.w / 2
        bottom: - sceneRoot.h / 2
        top: sceneRoot.h / 2
        nearPlane:   0.1
        farPlane:    1000.0
        position:    Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 )
        viewCenter:  Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
        upVector:    Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
    }

    /* setup a 3D cube to be used as the 2D drawing surface for all Qt Quick 2 stuff */

    Entity {
        id: drawingSurface

        PlaneMesh {
            id: planeMesh
            width: sceneRoot.w
            height: sceneRoot.h
        }

        Transform {
            id: planeTransform
            translation: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0)
            rotationX: 90
        }

        TextureMaterial {
            id: planeMaterial
            texture: offscreenTexture  // created by qmlTexture below
        }

        Layer {
            id: backgroundLayer
        }

        // picked up by Scene2D’s "entities" property and used as a source for events
        ObjectPicker {
            id: planePicker
            hoverEnabled: false
            dragEnabled: false
        }

        components: [ planeMesh, planeMaterial, planeTransform, planePicker, backgroundLayer ]
    }

    /* setup Scene2D offscreen texture to be used as canvas by Qt Quick 2 */

    Scene2D {
        id: qmlTexture
        output: RenderTargetOutput {
            attachmentPoint: RenderTargetOutput.Color0
            texture: Texture2D {
                id: offscreenTexture
                width: sceneRoot.w
                height: sceneRoot.h
                format: Texture.RGBA8_UNorm
                generateMipMaps: true
                magnificationFilter: Texture.Linear
                minificationFilter: Texture.LinearMipMapLinear
                wrapMode {
                    x: WrapMode.ClampToEdge
                    y: WrapMode.ClampToEdge
                }
            }
        }

        mouseEnabled: false
        entities: [ drawingSurface ]

        /* Qt Quick 2 rendering */

        Rectangle {
            width: offscreenTexture.width
            height: offscreenTexture.height
            x: 0
            y: 0
            border.color: "red"
            color: "green"

            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log("Outter rectangle size: " + width + "x" + height + " at " + x + "," + y);
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: innerRect
                height: parent.height*0.6
                width: height
                x: (parent.width/2) - (width/2)
                y: (parent.height/2) - (height/2)
                border.color: "red"
                color: "yellow"
                transform: Rotation { origin.x: innerRect.width/2; origin.y: innerRect.height/2; angle: 45}

                Component.onCompleted: {
                    console.log("Inner rectangle size: " + width + "x" + height + " at " + x + "," + y);
                }
            }
        }

    } // Scene2D

    /* add light source at the same place as the camera */

    Layer {
        id: mainLayer
    }

    Entity {
        PointLight {
            id: light
            color: "white"
            intensity: 1
            constantAttenuation: 1.0
            linearAttenuation: 0.0
        }

        Transform {
            id: lightTransform
            translation: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, sceneRoot.camZ)
        }

        components: [ light, lightTransform, mainLayer ]
    }

    /* display 3D object */

    Entity {
        SphereMesh {
            id: mesh
            radius: 130
        }

        PhongMaterial {
            id: material
            ambient: "blue"
        }

        Transform {
           id: transform
           translation: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0)
       }

       components: [ mesh, material, transform, mainLayer ]
   }

} // sceneRoot
```

Result screenshot:

[image]

By the way: Your code produces buggy results due to the drawing on an offscreen surface. I recommend you create and actual offscreen rendering framegraph and draw your stuff in there. Checkout [this very nice and informative GitHub repo](https://github.com/alpqr/q3dpostproc) and [my C++ Qt3D offscreen renderer implementation](https://github.com/florianblume/Qt3D-OffscreenRenderer).

Maybe as a side note: You could definitely achieve the same result by using perspective projection. You can read on perspective projection on the internet, e.g. [here](https://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/%7Ethormae/lectures/graphics1/graphics_6_1_eng_web.html#1). Essentially, you have a linear system of equestions where you know the pixel coordinates (where you want your plane to appear on screen) and solve for the 3D points of the plane. But it might get complicated, I'm sure the solution I posted is easier to use ;)

Comment: Excellent! I tried using Ortho projection initially but for whatever reason I couldn't get it to work and things were still being rendered with perspective. I was about to finish the calculation from 2D screen coordinate to the 3D world when you added the answer, thx vm! You gave us enough material to study. This answer deserves a lot more up-votes, people!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)